# OpenCL - Sync and Signal?

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, opencl

I want to use a sync-signal setting in OpenCL to make sure, that only one thread can go into a critical kernel part.
Here is the code, I have so far:

```
void sync(int barrierID) {
    int ID = get_global_id(0);
    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
    while (ID - barrierID != 0) {
        barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
    }
}

//critical part

void signal(int threadCount, int barrierID) {
    barrierID++;
    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
    while (barrierID != threadCount) {
        barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
    }
    barrierID = 0;
}
```

with threadcount for the amount of threads, that wnat to access the critical part and barrierID is the counter for how many threads has passed this part.

unfortunally, this code does not work in OpenCL.

Does anyone knows, how to fix this code?

Answer (score 1):

You are approaching GPU computing as a multi thread computing, which is completely wrong approach.

The reason is that in GPU computing all the "threads" (in reality they are work items), run at the same time. A work item cannot enter a zone, run code, while the others are doing something else.

Therefore, having any type of branching in the GPU is a terrible idea, since it will slow down your application, making the GPU run all the branches, even if some items do not enter in that case.

**For your specific case:**

You are getting a deadlock in your kernel because you are creating a barrier in a branch. After one single work item enters, will wait until all the others have entered. If that case does never happen, then you have a deadlock.

Check the barrier command: [`https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/barrier.html`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/barrier.html)

> If barrier is inside a conditional statement, then all work-items must enter the conditional if any work-item enters the conditional statement and executes the barrier.

Comment: Agreed. Related to this, when you use `barrier` you must ensure that all work items in a work group hit it. So anytime you have one inside a conditional it is suspect.

Comment: i do understand this, but my problem is, that i have one critical line (in about 1k lines), where the threads have to enter individually.

any idea how to do this?

Comment: No, there is no way to sync globally the threads at a given point in a kernel. You have to create multiple kernels.